# syntax of multiple ternary operators in ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ternary-operator

I'm trying to have some if statements in a javascript ajax call and I feel like it should be possible, just maybe my syntax is wrong. I'm trying to create the schedule part below:

```
$.ajax({
                type    :  'POST',
                name    :  'Submitting Request',
                url     :   '/breadcrumbs/crumb',
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : {
                    parameters  : paramsObj,
                    schedule: {       paramsObj.isfirst   ? firstSched
                                    : paramsObj.issecond  ? secondSched
                                    : paramsObj.isthird   ? thirdSched
                              }
                          },
            success  : function(){},
            error   : function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
       });
```

I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." around this block, specifically on the schedule line:

```
             data   : {
                parameters  : paramsObj,
                schedule: {       paramsObj.isfirst    ? firstSched
                                : paramsObj.issecond ? secondSched
                                : paramsObj.isthird ? thirdSched
                          }
                      },
```

for schedule in particular, this is what i'm trying to do with the ternary operators:

```
if( paramsObj.isfirst === true) { schedule = firstSched}
if( paramsObj.issecond === true){ schedule = secondSched}
if( paramsObj.isthird === true) { schedule = thirdSched}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the `{ }` around the expression are not needed

Comment: For the sake of your future self and your colleagues, don't do that! It's very difficult to read.

Comment: Nested ternary operators are evil. Move the code out into a separate block, or even a function and use if/else or switch.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/One-Bad-Ternary-Operator-Deserves-Another

Comment: honestly, i hate ternarys but i was trying to do it the traditional way and couldn't get it to work either (moving it out into a separate block and such). Most examples I found online that were working were ternaries so I tried to go that route. thanks for the quick responses guys!

Comment: I think the more readable route is to use an immediately-invoked function expression. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27823639/361762) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just the relevant field**:

```
schedule: paramsObj.isfirst ? firstSched : 
    paramsObj.issecond ? secondSched :
    paramsObj.isthird ? thirdSched : undefined
```

**Full call**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    name: 'Submitting Request',
    url: '/breadcrumbs/crumb',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        parameters: paramsObj,
        schedule: paramsObj.isfirst ? firstSched : 
            paramsObj.issecond ? secondSched :
            paramsObj.isthird ? thirdSched : undefined,
        success: function(){},
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
   });
```

**Note**

As others have pointed out, chaining ternaries can be hard to read, which can lead to bugs and maintenance problems. I personally don't mind chaining them, as long as they are broken out per line, as shown, so that they are easy to follow...

Comment: Thank you! I picked this as the solution because my question was about the ternary version, but because of such a large response against ternaries, I ended up going with a modified version of dave's answer for my code.

Answer (score 2):

Nested ternaries can be difficult to read. I'd suggest rewriting this as an [Immediately-executed function expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to make it much more readable:

```
schedule: (function() {
    if (paramsObj.isfirst)
        return firstSched;
    else if (paramsObj.issecond)
        return secondSched;
    else if (paramsObj.isthird)
        return thirdSched;
    else
        return undefined;
})();
```

Comment: Just a note - your code isn't exactly the same as what he says he is trying to do... for instance, if all three are false, his code shouldn't set schedule to thirdSched, but yours does...

Comment: @sethflowers thanks I didn't read that carefully enough--I fixed it and removed the part of my answer that was redundant with yours.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I ended up using this as my final solution, but did have to modify it like Seth flowers noted and you corrected in your answer. You were both extremely helpful!